# Angular version 4.x Table Row Component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a component that can be used as a row in a table.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <my-row *ngFor="let id of ids" [id]="id"></my-row>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I do this, all of the rows appear on a single row.

Here's an example of what the problem is and what I'm expecting.

https://plnkr.co/edit/37fRFlMNVqoQTg4UKBcu?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve desired result by using attribute selector

```
<tr my-row *ngFor="let id of ids"  [id]="id"></tr>

@Component({
  selector: '[my-row]',
  template: `<td>{{ id }}</td>`,
})
export class Row {
  @Input() id;
}
```

**[Forked Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/vUen7gz1nsaBt7Swwz3d?p=preview)**